# Shiny application started with Rscript and CMD is unavailable after time

Tags: r, shiny, rscript

I have a small .bat script that runs an app using "Rscript" when the user logs in. After some time, the application / server becomes unavailable. There is no error, the page only loads for forever.  When the app is started manually through RStudio there is no problem with the access to the app even after days of running. Any idea what causes this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/running.html) will help you. It is supposed to be the correct way to launch a R Shiny app.

```r
R -e "shiny::runApp('~/shinyapp')"
```

(1st result on Google ... Pardon my tone, but have you searched for this before to ask Stackoverflow how to deal with this problem?)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I have not seen this. I may have googled with wrong keyword.  Anyway, this solution is not suitable since "By default runApp starts the application on a randomly selected port."  I need it to be a fixed port so other colleagues can always access the page.  The shiny app itself contains the runApp command with set IP an port. I am able to run it as `Rscript "my_path.R"` but as said after some time the app becomes unavailable.

Comment: I then look at [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/runApp.html). Maybe the `port` argument will help? 
Then the command line would look like:
`R -e "options(shiny.port = XX); shiny::runApp('~/shinyapp')"`
Also check [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/RHOME/library/base/html/options.html) for further details on `options()`.

Comment: Thank you, I was adding the arguments before but unsuccessfully. With your help I managed to get it up and running. I also had to add an argument for the Ip address. So in the end it looked like this: `R -e "options(shiny.port = XXX);options(shiny.host = 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX') ; shiny::runApp('path_app.R')"`  I quickly tested the site and it seems to be working just fine. I will check in a while if it is still running.